# Filtering content with select form options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Im developing a WordPress Theme i need filter content using a form with three selector, for example i've Region, Specialist, Place

When user select one value from Region -> Specialist -> Place, user can see content from these three values selected

- If Region have value: "Region A"
- If Specialist have value: "Lawyer"
- If Place have value: "Chicago"

User only can see content of **Region A, Lawyer and Chicago**.

Currently i try this link [How can I filter out a div from two select options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864124/how-can-i-filter-out-a-div-from-two-select-options)

On HTML works fine, but i can't understand how to use WP_Query to filter the content on divs

To the forms i've this code:

```html
<form method="get">
 <select id="select_rubro">
  <option value="null"><?php _e('Rubro', 'cape'); ?></option>
  <?php
        //list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
        $taxonomy = 'rubro';
        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>

        <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { 
            echo '<option value="' .$tax_term->slug. '">' .$tax_term->name. '</option>';
        } ?>
 </select>
 <select id="select_especialidad" class="middle">
  <option value="null"><?php _e('Especialidad', 'cape'); ?></option>
  <?php
        //list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
        $taxonomy = 'especialidad';
        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>

        <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { 
            echo '<option value="' .$tax_term->slug. '">' .$tax_term->name. '</option>';
        } ?>
 </select>
 <select id="select_region">
  <option value="null"><?php _e('Región', 'cape'); ?></option>
  <?php
        //list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
        $taxonomy = 'region';
        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>

        <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { 
            echo '<option value="' .$tax_term->slug. '">' .$tax_term->name. '</option>';
        } ?>
 </select>
</form>
```

In the snippet i call all terms values from taxonomies declared.

Any idea? In advance thank you and excuse my english

Answer (score 0):

As you want to display data to your user according to drop down selection where all terms are separate in word press admin (no hierarchy)

I suggest you to use Ajax functionality in which put one blank  below all drop down with unique class/id on page load.

Pass all selected value of drop down (term ids) in Ajax file and run below wp_query to get filter records.

you can get id of term from drop down value if you replace with slug and pass into in ajax file.

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'put custom taxonomy name',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => array_values($ids_of_terms)
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

you can append Ajax respose of div by replace with blank div and display results as well.